# How to Create InputStream Object from JsonObject

Tags: java, json, file, rest, inputstream

I'm trying to figure out how one goes about retrieving the raw bytes stored in a JsonObject and turns that into an InputStream object?

I figured it might be something like:

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream((File)json.getJsonObject("data"));
```

Granted I haven't tried that out, but just wanted to know if anyone had any experience with this and knew the preferred way to do it?

Comment: Just in case if you ever run into a situation where you have to stream the content of a very large JSON object, which might produce OutOfMemory errors on `toString()` method invocations use mutliple ByteArrayInputStreams as prestented [in this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7099314/1377895)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can convert a `JSONObject` into its `String` representation, and then convert that String into an `InputStream`.

The code in the question has a JSONObject being cast into `File`, but I am not sure if that works as intended. The following, however, is something I have done before (currently reproduced from memory):

```
String str = json.getJSONObject("data").toString();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
```

Note that the `toString()` method for `JSONObject` overrides the one in `java.lang.Object` class.

From the [Javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()):

> **Returns:** a printable, displayable, portable, transmittable representation of the object, beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).

Comment: So your solution does work, but I have a question as far as if you pass a file down into your rest call, why does it automatically convert that into an InputStream on the java side?

Comment: The `String` is converted to a sequence of bytes, which is, in turn, converted to an `InputStream`.

Comment: Note that tostring method of JSONObject is not safe for non-ascii chars. It won't encode in utf-8

Answer (score 7):

if you want bytes, use this

```
json.toString().getBytes()
```

or write a File `savedFile` contains json.toString, and  then

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(savedFile);
```