# new line for every new stream in SequenceInputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io

I have two files, `test-1.text` (content is `Data from test-1`) and `test-2.text` (content is `Data from test-2`).
 when I use `SequenceInputStream` to read from two streams, output comes either in one straight line like `Data from test-1Data from test-2` or every character is on new line.
 How can I start to print content from the second stream in a new line?

```
public class SequenceIStream {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fi1 = new FileInputStream("resources/test-1.text");
    FileInputStream fi2 = new FileInputStream("resources/test-2.text");

    SequenceInputStream seq = new SequenceInputStream(fi1, fi2);

    int i= 0;

    while((i = seq.read())!=-1)
        System.out.print((char)i);
}
```

}

Output is
`Data from test-1Data from test-2`

Desired output
`Data from test-1`
`Data from test-2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I based this response on [this helpful SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099279/adding-characters-to-beginning-and-end-of-inputstream-in-java) which provides a method for creating a `SequenceInputStream` from a collection of streams.  The basic idea here is that you already have two streams which give the output you want.  You only need a line break, more specifically a *stream* which generates a line break.  We can simply create a `ByteArrayInputStream` from the bytes of a newline string, and then sandwich it in between the file streams you already have.

```
FileInputStream fi1 = new FileInputStream("resources/test-1.text");
FileInputStream fi2 = new FileInputStream("resources/test-2.text");

String newLine = "\n";
List<InputStream> streams = Arrays.asList(
    fi1,
    new ByteArrayInputStream(newLine.getBytes()),
    fi2);
InputStream seq = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(streams));

int i= 0;

while((i = seq.read())!=-1)
    System.out.print((char)i);
```

Comment: The List and Collections.enumeration seems unnecessary for the purpose of this example, but I like the overall solution.

Comment: @aglassman Yes it does seem unnecessary.  In practice I'd probably just edit the file :-)

Comment: without List and collection, `SequenceInputStream` object can not be created with more than 2 `InputStream` objects.

Answer (score 1):

SequenceInputStream doesn't support this option. The only way to fix that ist to add a newline ('\n') character to the content of the file `test-1.text` (content: `Data from test-1\n`)

Comment: Yup, otherwise you're defeating the purpose of SequenceInputStream.