# Uploading a file to a FTP server from android phone?

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

Following is the code that's suppose to create a text document and upload it to my FTP server. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. I used to the libraries provided at

http://lavalatwork.blogspot.tw/2010/09/using-apache-commons-ftp-library-in.html

for communicating with the FTP server.

```
try
    {
        final String testString = new String("Hello");
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

        osw.write(testString);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }


    catch(IOException ex)
    {

    }


    FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();
    try {
        // Connect to FTP Server
        mFTP.connect("192.168.10.101");
        //mFTP.login("user", "password");
        mFTP.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        // Prepare file to be uploaded to FTP Server
        File file = new File(getFileStreamPath("samplefile.txt")+ "");
        FileInputStream ifile = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Upload file to FTP Server
        mFTP.storeFile("filetotranfer",ifile);
        mFTP.disconnect();          
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Checking the output of logcat is often very helpful when using Apache Commons FTP client.

Comment: Please be explicit about what exactly does not work. And post your logcat.

Answer (score 23):

See this...... This will help you rectify the probs in your code.

I have used the **apache's commons library** to upload and download an Audio file to and from the Server... see this...

**Uploading:**

```
public void goforIt(){


        FTPClient con = null;

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("192.168.2.57");

            if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
                in.close();
                if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }






    }
```

**Downloading:**

```
public void goforIt(){
    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("192.168.2.57");

        if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.retrieveFile("vivekm4a.m4a", out);
            out.close();
            if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("download result","failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use  [Simple Java FTP Client](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/)  and add it as external jar for your project, you can also refer to this [link](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/file-upload-and-download-using-java/)

```
public class FileUpload
{

   /**
    * Upload a file to a FTP server. A FTP URL is generated with the
    * following syntax:
    * ftp://user:password@host:port/filePath;type=i.
    *
    * @param ftpServer , FTP server address (optional port ':portNumber').
    * @param user , Optional user name to login.
    * @param password , Optional password for user.
    * @param fileName , Destination file name on FTP server (with optional
    *            preceding relative path, e.g. "myDir/myFile.txt").
    * @param source , Source file to upload.
    * @throws MalformedURLException, IOException on error.
    */
   public void upload( String ftpServer, String user, String password,
         String fileName, File source ) throws MalformedURLException,
         IOException
   {
      if (ftpServer != null &amp;&amp; fileName != null &amp;&amp; source != null)
      {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );
         // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
         if (user != null &amp;&amp; password != null)
         {
            sb.append( user );
            sb.append( ':' );
            sb.append( password );
            sb.append( '@' );
         }
         sb.append( ftpServer );
         sb.append( '/' );
         sb.append( fileName );
         /*
          * type ==&gt; a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file directory
          * listing
          */
         sb.append( ";type=i" );

         BufferedInputStream bis = null;
         BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
         try
         {
            URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlc.getOutputStream() );
            bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( source ) );

            int i;
            // read byte by byte until end of stream
            while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
            {
               bos.write( i );
            }
         }
         finally
         {
            if (bis != null)
               try
               {
                  bis.close();
               }
               catch (IOException ioe)
               {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
            if (bos != null)
               try
               {
                  bos.close();
               }
               catch (IOException ioe)
               {
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
               }
         }
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println( "Input not available." );
      }
   }
```

You can also use the [Apache commons-net-ftp](http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar.html) library, for more details you can focus on this [link](http://royvandewater.com/2010/10/uploading-a-file-to-ftp-with-android/).

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

try {
    ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER));
    ftpClient.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH);

    if (ftpClient.getReplyString().contains("250")) {
        ftpClient.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
        buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(FULL_PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE));
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ProgressInputStream progressInput = new ProgressInputStream(buffIn, progressHandler);

        boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(localAsset.getFileName(), progressInput);
        buffIn.close();
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }

} catch (SocketException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(SorensonApplication.TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```

Comment: Should we set something on Manifest to get internet connection permission?

Comment: someSocket problem occurs, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code block :

```
private class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        try {
            client.connect(params[1], PORT);
            client.login(params[2], params[3]);
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            return client.storeFile(filename, new FileInputStream(new File(
                    params[0])));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("FTP", e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean sucess) {
        if (sucess)
            Toast.makeText(activity, "File Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Please get complete working project for uploading files to FTP server from below drive.

File uploading to FTP is used PORT 21,
required parameter to upload file on FTP..

host name
username
password

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80LBJs3JkaDYUNfZ3pDSkVJUDA/edit

Comment: Thanks @FelixSFD I have edited my answer pls look into this. Is it fine now ?