# get picture from FTP server then convert to Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, ftp, jpeg

Based on an answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600988/uploading-a-file-to-a-ftp-server-from-android-phone), we can upload and download from FTP server:

```
//UPLOAD
try
{
    FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
    con.connect("192.168.2.57");

    if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
    {
        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
        boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
        in.close();
        if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//DOWNLOAD
try
{
    FTPClient con = new FTPClient();
    con.connect("192.168.2.57");

    if (con.login("Administrator", "KUjWbk"))
    {
        con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
        con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        String data = "/sdcard/vivekm4a.m4a";

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(data));
        boolean result = con.retrieveFile("vivekm4a.m4a", out);
        out.close();
        if (result) Log.v("download result", "succeeded");
        con.logout();
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.v("download result","failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In download part, is it possible to just retrieve the file (assuming the file is always jpg) and convert it to Bitmap without having to create a file in my application's folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [picaso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to get the image downloaded from FTP server and obtain its bitmap.
Picasso library has special method "[target](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html)" which will directly provide you the downloaded bitmap for you code.
Hope it will help you.
e.g

```
Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {       
       // You can use the bitmap object here
      }
      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed() {
      }
}
 Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(target);
```